# How to take camera picture from google ml kit face detector?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-camera, google-mlkit

i try camera picture use https://github.com/fernandoptrr/flutter-camera-practice, this work fine with XFile picture = await _cameraController.takePicture();

then try google ml kit example, https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin . I try face detector and try screenshot with takePicture(). It give "Error occured while taking picture cannot use a surface that wasn't configured".

can someone give me example take picture camera with google ml kit?

Comment: btw, i use android camera and ml kit can detect the face

Comment: https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin is neither owned nor endorsed by Google or Google ML Kit. Please use their Issues page (https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/issues) to report.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look this github project [FaceRecognitionAuth](https://github.com/MCarlomagno/FaceRecognitionAuth)

you can find full face recognition authentication in this project.
also if you want to make your own then there need to be some config that you need to be follow.
Like when you are set up your

> tflite_flutter

package. you need to configure [Initial setup](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter#important-initial-setup--add-dynamic-libraries-to-your-app.)